# Xamarin forms - Error when toggling entry view's IsPassword (only on uwp)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following sample app code:

App.cs (Entry Point)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public class ListItem
    {
        public string ItemText { get; set; }
        public string ItemDetail { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }


    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            var listView = new ListView
            {
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    var textCell = new TextCell();
                    textCell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "ItemText");
                    textCell.SetBinding(TextCell.DetailProperty, "ItemDetail");
                    return textCell;
                }),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                ItemsSource = new List<ListItem>
                {
                    new ListItem
                    {
                        ItemText = "Item 1",
                        ItemDetail = "Detail 1",
                        Password = "123456"
                    },

                    new ListItem
                    {
                        ItemText = "Item 2",
                        ItemDetail = "Detail 2",
                        Password = "76432"
                    },
                    new ListItem
                    {
                        ItemText = "Item 3",
                        ItemDetail = "Detail 3",
                        Password = "66543"
                    },
                }
            };

            listView.ItemTapped += ListView_ItemTapped;

            var content = new ContentPage
            {
                Title = "App1",
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children =
                    {
                        new ScrollView
                        {
                            Content = new StackLayout
                            {
                                Padding = 10,
                                Children =
                                {
                                    listView
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(content);
        }

        private async void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            await this.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new PasswordPage((e.Item as ListItem).Password));
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

PasswordPage.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public class PasswordPage : ContentPage
    {
        private string Password;
        private Entry PasswordEntry = new Entry();

        public PasswordPage(string password)
        {
            this.Password = password;
            PasswordEntry.IsPassword = true;
            PasswordEntry.Text = password;

            var button = new Button();
            button.Text = "Show/Hide";
            button.Clicked += Button_Clicked;

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    new Label { Text = "Password" },
                    PasswordEntry,
                    button
                }
            };
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PasswordEntry.IsPassword = !PasswordEntry.IsPassword;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error in the following scenario, only on UWP (you can [download](http://filebin.ca/2vvUfFaTY86L/PasswordBug.zip) the attached sample project,  run the UWP project and follow the guide to reproduce):

1. On the main application page click any item of the ListView.
2. On the page that opens, click the "Show/Hide" button **twice**.
3. Go back to the previous page.
4. Click any item of the ListView again.

The error occurs only on UWP/Windows and only if you toggle the "IsPassword" property of an "Entry" view. If you click the "Show/Hide" once, then the error does not appear.

Error:

> System.ArgumentException
>
> The parameter is incorrect.
>
> E_RUNTIME_SETVALUE
>
> at Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp,
>   Object value)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.EntryRenderer.UpdateIsPassword()    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.EntryRenderer.OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs'1
>   e)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer'2.SetElement(VisualElement
>   element)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.CreateRenderer(VisualElement
>   element)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded(Object
>   sender, ElementEventArgs e)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.Load()    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer'2.SetElement(VisualElement
>   element)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.CreateRenderer(VisualElement
>   element)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded(Object
>   sender, ElementEventArgs e)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementPackager.Load()    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer'2.SetElement(VisualElement
>   element)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.CreateRenderer(VisualElement
>   element)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementExtensions.GetOrCreateRenderer(VisualElement
>   self)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.NavigationPageRenderer.SetPage(Page page,
>   Boolean isAnimated, Boolean isPopping)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.NavigationPageRenderer.OnPushRequested(Object
>   sender, NavigationRequestedEventArgs e)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.d__90.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.d__48.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at App1.App.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.b__6_0(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()

[Download Project Sample](http://filebin.ca/2vvUfFaTY86L/PasswordBug.zip)

Comment: what you try to do with this?

 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PasswordEntry.IsPassword = !PasswordEntry.IsPassword;
        }

Comment: I am trying to toggle the PasswordEntry's appearance as a password (show or hide the text with asterisks). Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sqhs5fs1/2/

Comment: your code is working in my pc. I dont watch any errors

Comment: You executed the UWP project and followed the guide exactly and you got no errors? I get the error both on my PC as well as on my windows 10 phone

Comment: I execute the code in my pc windows 10 pro, with your code, and I don't have any issue.

Comment: What version you have of the UWP build?

Comment: My version of UWP is Build 10586

Comment: I am using 14393. I can reproduce it on my other pc too. The target does not seem to matter. Are you sure you are clicking the button **twice**, then go back, then click on the list again?

Comment: Yes I try twice and back to te menu. I think is a issue of the 14393 I can try more later if you dont solve yer, try compile with the version 10586.

Comment: I tried with 10586, but no difference. The problem persists :/

Comment: If you want I share my code with you. And run in your pc.

Comment: Sure, why not. Lets give it a shot.

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!6BFlxQ6Y  here is the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is actually a bug in Forms. I've submitted a bug report for it [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44954).

The issue seems to be related to setting the native TextBox control InputScope property. I created a [pull request](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/405) for a fix so hopefully this gets merged and released soon.